# What is the syntax to call parameterized ms-access function from java script?

Tags: javascript, ms-access, activex

I have a function called "test" in module of ms-access. I call this respective function from javascript. Below is the sample code :

```
            var App = new ActiveXObject("Access.Application")
            var fullPath = "Path of accdb file";
            App.OpenCurrentDatabase(fullPath);
            App.Visible = false;
            var sub = App.Run("test"); // i am calling test procedure, which is public in module and dont require any input parameter.
```

This works fine.

Now, I made changes to function test. Function test has a string as input parameter(ie Public Function test(String as a) As Integer). How to make call to test function from java script?

Answer (score 1):

Function Run(Procedure As String, [Arg1], [Arg2], [Arg3], [Arg4], [Arg5], [Arg6], [Arg7], [Arg8], [Arg9], [Arg10], [Arg11], [Arg12], [Arg13], [Arg14], [Arg15], [Arg16], [Arg17], [Arg18], [Arg19], [Arg20], [Arg21], [Arg22], [Arg23], [Arg24], [Arg25], [Arg26], [Arg27], [Arg28], [Arg29], [Arg30])

```
var sub = App.Run("test","SOME input parameter STRING")
```